# Why is ExclusionsStyle not working as expected?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, style

I have the following script

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

b1BlSmall = {4.17891*^-1, 5.59816*^-1, 7.09626*^-1, 4.17891*^-1};
b1BlLarge = {3.15389*^-1, 4.73084*^-1, 6.85972*^-1, 3.62698*^-1};
b2BlSmall = {9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1};
b2BlLarge = {9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 9.74949*^-1, 2.00000};
dbhAdult = {1.00000*^1, 1.00000*^1, 1.00000*^1, 5.48121};

C2B = 2.0
pftColor = {Green, Darker[Green], Darker[Darker[Green]], Magenta};

size2bl[dbh_, ipft_, a_: 1, b_: 1, c_: 1] := 
  If[ipft != 
    4, \[Piecewise]b1BlSmall[[ipft]]/C2B*dbh^b2BlSmall[[ipft]] dbh < 
    dbhAdult[[ipft]] b1BlLarge[[ipft]]/C2B*
     dbh^b2BlLarge[[ipft]] True, \[Piecewise](a*b1BlSmall[[ipft]])/
      C2B*dbh^(b*b2BlSmall[[ipft]]) dbh < 
    dbhAdult[[ipft]] (a*b1BlLarge[[ipft]])/C2B*
     dbh^(c*b2BlLarge[[ipft]]) True];

putzbl[dbh_] := (0.0856*dbh^2 - 0.376)/C2B;

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Flatten@{putzbl[dbh], 
     Table[size2bl[dbh, ipft, a, b, c], {ipft, 1, 4}]}, {dbh, 0.0, 
   11.0},
  PlotStyle -> Flatten[{Black, pftColor}], 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic],
 {a, 0.8, 1.2}, {b, 0.8, 1.2}, {c, 0.8, 1.2}]
```

which produces the following graphs:

[image]

Why is `EclusionsStyle` producing a black line over the discontinuities instead of one matching the curve color? How do I fix that.
By the way, strangely when I drag the manipulate cursors the colors change to the desired one.

Comment: Your code produces errors, probably due to the `\[Piecewise]`. Try converting to InputForm and edit you post accordingly.

Comment: It may depend on the mathematica version. I tried to copy back the text from my post to a new nb and for me it works (version 8). I actually copied it as input text.

Answer (score 1):

It actually worked just with setting `Exclusions->None`.